# How can I throw a custom error with PHP to .catch(error => {console.log(error)} Axios

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I'm new to JavaScript and PHP. I want to throw a custom error from my PHP to `axios.catch`, but I can't figure out how to do it. For example:

PHP:

```php
 if ($username === 'admin' && $password === '123') {
    echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
  } else {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Invalid username or         
password']);
  }
```

axios:

```js
axios.post('login.php', { username, password })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        // handle successful login
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        console.log( error: 'Invalid username or password'); <<something like this
      });
```

Thanks!

Searching the internet, I only found the catch to work when, for example, you throw a 400 error in PHP, but if I want to throw a custom error, I don't know how I can do it.

My question is: what do I need to do in PHP in order to send a custom error to axios' `.catch`

Comment: Not familiar with Axios but I would guess that the catch requires an actual HTTP error. Sending a JSON packet that contains the text `error` isn't an error. You'll probably need to also issue a 403 status header.

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: ah!! ok ok i figured it out thanks you, its wrong to handle error inside .then{if(error){code...}} and in .catch header error ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the HTTP response status code to a non-successful status code (e.g. 400, 401, etc.) and include the error message in the response body and then access the error message in axios .catch method by reading 'response.data'

PHP:

```
if ($username === 'admin' && $password === '123') {
    echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
} else {
    http_response_code(401); // set HTTP response status code to 401 Unauthorized
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Invalid username or password']);
}
```

JS:

```
axios.post('login.php', { username, password })
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    // handle successful login
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    console.log(error.response.data.error); // log error message
});
```